# Crosshair in Flex mx Charts for mobile applications

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, charts

I am trying to implement Stock Charts in my Mobile application created in flex.

what i need to implement is the cross hair  as seen in http://www.rb.com/Media-investors/Share-price-information/Share-price-graph

kindly advice how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/ChartSampler/app.html).

Customization -> Custom Annotation. To view source - mouse right click -> "View Source".

Comment: i already tried using that and was able to display the cross hairs but  but it does not fulfill my requirement. what i need is some kind of tooltip(or the object) when i touch anywhere on the chart, it should give me the data point lying closest to the  vertical axis  at that point. i tried using the property getItemsInRegion by specifying a rect of small width. but its performance is sketchy at best. also it is not the ideal solution as it can be deceptive where the chart has a steep slope.